# Mapbox.js rendering blank in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, mapbox

I - a beginner at Ruby on Rails, HTML and CSS - am trying to render a Mapbox.js map in my Rails application. However, the map does not show up. As you can see in the picture, the zoom controls do show up correctly.
[image: Mapbox not showing up]
When trying to resolve the error, I came across [this](https://www.mapbox.com/help/blank-tiles/) FAQ. I have confirmed that my access token, map ID and account usage limits are not the problem.

The following is my code:

```
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.0.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet'/>

<div class="content">
  <% if @points[@unit.name] != nil && @points[@unit.name].length %>

      <div id='map' style="
          position: relative;
          margin-left: -10px;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 700px;
          height: 700px;">
      </div>

      <script type='text/javascript'>
          L.mapbox.accessToken = 'heres-my-access-token';
          var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.satellite').setView([52.214360, 6.860573], 8);
      </script>

  <% end %>

... other <div>s

</div>

<script>
    $('map').show();
    map.invalidateSize();
</script>
```

I'm working in a pretty large application so the problem is probably caused by styling or something. I checked according to the FAQ tips and the elements on the page are not set as initially 'hidden' anywhere. I am not quite sure whether my invalidateSize() command is placed correctly though...

I'm now pretty much stuck - does someone have other ideas to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that it wouldn't load the mapbox.js script because of the Content Security Policy directive.

I found this out by going to the browser console, which I hadn't thought of trying before. Here I found the errors related to mapbox (e.g. 'Refused to load the script because....'.

I fixed it by whitelisting mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

Should `$('map').show();` be `$('#map').show();`?

You can also check if this is firing too soon, by only running it on doc ready i.e.

```
$(function() {
  $('#map').show();
  map.invalidateSize();
});
```